# In Vue, how can I change one element generated by a v-for statement?

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue app, I have a list of items that can be added to the basket generated by a `v-for`. I want to have it so that when the 'add to basket' button for an item is clicked, the text for the button on *just that item* changes to 'added' or whatever.

If I set the button text as a variable and update it when I call my `addToBasket()` function, it sets the text on *all* the items generated by the v-for, so every Add to Basket button in the list changes to 'added'. I want to target just the clicked button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you could do this, you need someway of tracking what is in the basket on a per-item basis.

For example, we could have a template like this;

```html
<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in basket">
      {{ item.text }}
      <button type="button" @click="item.added = !item.added">
        <span v-if="item.added">Remove from basket</span>
        <span v-else>Add to basket</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Where we iterate with a `v-for` each item in the basket. When the button is clicked for that item, it will toggle the state on just that item. We can then use that state to determine what text we show in the button next to it.

Example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8bjfd3am/1/).

Comment: Well, I guess I gave very superficial information - _mea culpa_. The basket is stored in a VueX store, so the addToBasket function has the item information passed to it. I guess I just don't know how to limit the update to just the clicked item. Ideally what I'd like is to just update the button text briefly then set it back to the default, so they can add the item again.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall ok, I have updated the fiddle - I think the principle is more or less the same though, you need some way of tracking the state per item.